# Style compound paths in svg as one entity

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm using AI to create .svg files. The text is generated as multiple compound paths. I want to render all of the compound paths as if they are one.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Select all the text compound paths and make another compound path

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem by editing the .svg to combine compound paths. With an svg file I removed code to create a single path. I removed <path and attributes> + quotes on each end so that multiple paths become one path.